# Update MySQL won't work in java

Tags: java, mysql, database, api, sql-update

I've got a probleme, when I use Select query it works perfectly, but when I'm using my Update, it doesn't work? why?

I tried the query in mysql workbench, it worked but not in netbeans.

```
   package com.spanow.mavenproject2;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataBase {

    Connection con = null;

    public DataBase() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("parfaitement connecté");
        } catch (SQLException o) {
            System.out.println("erreur base de données");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException io) {
            System.out.println("lol");
        }

    }
```

This is my DataBase class which connects to the database, I have also a method in there, this one :

```
public String updateDemandeN1(int a) {
    if (a > 5) {
        return "khtak";
    }
    String sql = "UPDATE `test`.`demande` SET 'N1' = ? WHERE 'ID'= 3";

    try {
        PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, "PAS_ENCORE");
        st.executeUpdate();

        return "sh3ar o";

    } catch (SQLException IO) {

        return sql;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks to see the error. It doesn't help you one bit that you do `return sql;` and throw away the exception.

Comment: What's the symptom? Is there an exception? If your connection's autocommit is off, did you commit?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
 don't know why, but printStackTrace() doesn't show anything on my output, this is why I didn't use it, it somehow enter to my catch, but why, I don't know

Comment: put a breakpoint or use a logger to hava a look at the stacktrace, but chances are that it will be the key to your problem

Comment: Thank you for your time, I used breakpoint as you said, I find that the problem is with st.executeUpdate().
I still have to find why haha

Comment: Post your exception, so we can help!

Comment: Grave:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe près de ''N1' = 'PAS_ENCORE' WHERE 'ID'= 3' in line  1
Sorry it takes me time cauz I'm a noobie, I'm not used to Java neither netbeans

Comment: You have indeed a syntax error: N1 is a field, don't use quotes around it, and same for ID

Comment: It worked *-*
thank you for all my friend, you really was a good help for me